# Text going out of div column foundation zurb

Tags: css, html, laravel, zurb-foundation

Just trying to create simple template, but dont know why text going out of div. here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    @include('qhymchildz.includes.head')

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header" class="panel">
        ini headersssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
        </div>
        <div id="main" class="row">
            <div id="content" class="medium-10 columns panel">
                <p>contentssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
            </div>
            <div id="sidebar" align="left" class="medium-2 columns panel">
                <p>salfjasjf;lajfja;jsfl;;asjf;lawoierwruowirowuriowrowrowurioweruiowrowerowurowuriowrowrowuroirour</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" class="panel">
            ini footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the result
http://prntscr.com/5nwn5l

How to fix it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry as i cannot comment due to low reputation but is it possible to see your CSS code used as that would help alot.

At first sight it could be fixed by using `word-wrap: break-word` since you are using a solid line of text rather than that of one with spaces. if not that it may be an `overflow-x` issue. it may also be that if you are using a grid template as would be suggested by columns and rows, it may be an issue with that code that affects how the long string of text responds to lack of room.

Try breaking up that text into real words or some Lorem Ipsum

Really i would need to see your CSS, thanks.

Comment: yes bro , css detect my long word as one word , so it will break when i use 'word-wrap: break-word' , but if use real word like lorem ipsum i don't need to use break-word. thanks in advance.